# SPARQL Describe query not working on java

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I try to use sparql `describe` keyword.

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

DESCRIBE ?person WHERE {
  ?person rdf:type foaf:Person .
  FILTER EXISTS { ?person owl:sameAs ?sameAs }
}
LIMIT 100
```

My `describe` query is working on http://dbpedia.org/sparql.

I wrote java program which execute the query, but my code is not working.

```
ParameterizedSparqlString qs = new ParameterizedSparqlString( "" +
             "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> \r\n" + 
             "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\r\n" + 
             "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\r\n" + 
             "\r\n" + 
             "DESCRIBE ?person WHERE {\r\n" + 
             "  ?person rdf:type foaf:Person .\r\n" + 
             "  FILTER EXISTS { ?person owl:sameAs ?sameAs }\r\n" + 
             "}\r\n" + 
             "LIMIT 100");

     QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/sparql", qs.asQuery() );
     Model result = exec.execDescribe();
```

When I run `exec.execDescribe()`, I get this error :

> org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 898, col: 11]. 
>   Failed to find a prefix name or keyword: –(8211;0x2013).

Could you please help me why it's not working?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: If you want the community not to close your question, please edit your question and describe: the expected behaviour, and how it works now. It's better to add it into your question and not just in the comments.

Comment: It is a known issue with the returned data when using `CONSTRUCT` or `DESCRIBE` with Virtuoso. 2 related bugs have been reported. @TallTed Illegal Turtle and RDF/XML is returned, see the issues [569](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/569) and [567](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/567). Not sure if they will ever be fixed or whether they have already been fixed (if so, you should close them maybe?). At least for the public DBpedia endpoint, there are still those issues, see the parse error with the `–` char

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're right. The issue still continues. I couldn't execute my code.

Comment: Trying to recreate this, I get a different result set than you (because your query has no `ORDER BY`, among other things), so I cannot tell what was on line 898 of your output. Can you re-test, and provide the complete line of XML output which is flagged by the new `org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException` error? Best case, please also include the XML line with the subject which corresponds to the predicate and object in the error-flagged line.

Comment: @gambit - We (I work for OpenLink Software, maker of Virtuoso) want to solve this (if we haven't already), but we cannot do so without your help. Please answer my questions above ...

Comment: @TallTed Thank you for your intense attention. Sorry for delay. I changed my query like this (ORDER BY ?person). I get the same error again but now line is 540.

Comment: @gambit -- I don't think I'm getting the same output from DBpedia as you are, and that makes this issue difficult to impossible for me to diagnose further. Once again -- _Can you re-test, and provide the complete line of XML output which is flagged by the new `org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException` error? Best case, please also include the XML line with the subject which corresponds to the predicate and object in the error-flagged line._ Please also include the full error message, as it may not be exactly the same now.

Comment: @TallTed- I tried and get this error. [org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 540, col: 11] Failed to find a prefix name or keyword: “(8220;0x201C)].